# "App not installed" error after building android app with "expo build:android"

Tags: react-native, expo

after I ran `expo build:android` i got the apk file built successfully but when I try to install it in many devices, it is not being installed and it shows "App not installed" error [[image]](https://res.cloudinary.com/dqueufbs7/image/upload/v1556140443/images/Screen_Shot_2019-04-25_at_00.09.03.png).

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you upload it to the Play Store and download it from the Play Store?

Comment: No, it was in my local pc, just wanted to build apk file and test it on a real device.

Comment: If so, create an apk file again and click Ignore and Install when prompted to install.

Comment: @hongdevelop sorry but how do you mean of click ignore, where?

Comment: This is the click button for the notification window that comes out when you rebuild and download and install the apk.It's next to the confirmation button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the problem was in the android packager name in my app.json

so it was like that:

```
"package": "com.<myName>.<appName>"
```

i replaced myName with the appName like that :

```
"package": "com.<appName>.<appName>"
```

and it worked like a magic and I was able to successfully build and install the app on multiple devices

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to **uninstall** any previous version of the App installed as they may have the same package name.

Answer (score 3):

1. On your main screen of the phone, scroll down the status bar of the phone.
2. Select the “Airplane Mode”, and press “Turn ON”
3. Now go and try to install your application
4. While installing a notification may appear about “Blocked by Play Protect”
5. Then press “Install anyway”

Comment: This actually fixed my issue, but could you elaborate, why this is a valid solution?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was the disk space of my phone.

Solution:
-> Try to uninstall some apps and after this try to install. ;-) worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Those two solutions didn't make it for me. What made it for me was just to install the last Os on my phone and the apk install finally worked. Hope my answer can help someone as it took me a long time to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if your mobile device has space. I cleared up about 2GB of dummy data on my device and the app installed.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the problem was in the android packager name in my `app.json`, I was trying to use a `.digital` [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) =>

`"package": "digital.<mydomain>.<appname>"`

Hence, I had to revert back to:

`"package": "com.<mydomain>.<appname>"`

and the `.apk` can be downloaded after re-building the app.